# how to get filename from URL in javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my application am allowing the user to upload URL of the PDF file.  i want to grab only the file name from the URL.
For example: If user uploads the URL as www.gradsch.ohio-state.edu/Depo/ETD_Tutorial/lesson2.pdf than lesson2.pdf should get extracted
 code:

```
 function load_file(box) {
   var file = document.getElementById('file');
   if (file == "") {
       alert("Enter File URL");
       return false;
   }

   }
```

How can i grab only the file name from the URL

Answer (score 0):

As 
    **file.substring** 
you point on container and try to use substring method on it, not on it's content.

You should use 
    **file.innerHTML.substring** instead.

Comment: i did as u said but still am getting the same error. TypeError: 
file.innerHtml is undefined

...eturn file.innerHtml.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, file.lastIndexOf("."))

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `file.text() or file.val()`

Eg.:

```
return file.text().substring(file.text().lastIndexOf("/") + 1, file.text().lastIndexOf("."));
```

Or,

```
return file.val().substring(file.val().lastIndexOf("/") + 1, file.val().lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: file ? what type of html element it is ? Post the rendered html for the file element.

Comment: <a class="uploadURL" onclick="loadURL();">Load URL</a> 
 function loadURL(box) {
           var box = dhtmlx.modalbox({
               title: "Load URL",
               text: "<div id='form_in_box'><div>Enter the URL of PDF file <hr/><div><input type='text' id='file' style='width: 400px; height: 27px;'/><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='submit' value='Load URL' style='width: 86px' onclick='load_file(this)'></span><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='close_file(this)' style='width:80px;'></span></label></div></div>",
width: "300px"
  })
       }

Comment: 'file.val()' should work for you. file.val() will get the current value of the input element.

Comment: Am allowing the user to insert the URL in the textarea .. like www.gradsch.ohio-state.edu/Depo/ETD_Tutorial/lesson2.pdf
and than it calls the UploadURL action from FileUpload

Comment: Have you set any value for file text box, before calling load_file ?

Comment: OK, then do a check:   if (file.val() != "") {return file.val().substring(file.val().lastIndexOf("/") + 1, file.val().lastIndexOf("."));} alert(file.val());

Comment: I did as u said now also am getting error as
 TypeError: file.val is not a function
if (file.val() != "")